# Create New Columns by Dividing Values from Other Columns Based on Conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to create new columns that would look at the proportion of income for different expenses. This is what my data looks like:

```
df_inp <- read.delim(text="Individuals| quarter | wage | foodq1 | foodq2 | rentq1
1          | 2016q1  | 100  | 1      | 2      | 50
1          | 2016q2  | 100  | 1      | 2      | 50
1          | 2016q3  | 200  | 1      | 2      | 50
1          | 2016q4  | 300  | 1      | 2      | 50
2          | 2016q1  | 50   | 1      | 2      | 50
2          | 2016q2  | 100  | 1      | 2      | 50
2          | 2016q3  | 200  | 1      | 2      | 50
2          | 2016q4  | 100  | 1      | 2      | 50, sep="|")
```

For the proportion columns, I would like for them to look like this:

```
df_outp <- read.delim(text="Individuals| quarter | wage | pro.foodq1 | pro.foodq2 | pro.rentq1
1          | 2016q1  | 100  | .01        | .02        | .5
1          | 2016q2  | 100  | .01        | .02        | .5
1          | 2016q3  | 200  | .01        | .02        | .5
1          | 2016q4  | 300  | .01        | .02        | .5
2          | 2016q1  | 50   | .02        | .04        | 1
2          | 2016q2  | 100  | .02        | .04        | 1
2          | 2016q3  | 200  | .02        | .04        | 1
2          | 2016q4  | 100  | .02        | .04        | 1", sep="|")
```

I have tried using the `ifelse()` function, however, it created a lot of rows that were unnecessary and removing them was tedious and inefficient.

Comment: What's the logic that relates the data to the output?

Comment: I presume something like `df |> mutate(across(-(1:2), ~.x / sum(.x)), .by = Individuals)`. It would be nice to have the data in a reproducible format so I could test that.

Comment: If you run `dput(YOUR_DATA)` or `dput(head(YOUR_DATA, 8))` and paste the output into the body of your question, we could run code on data that has your data's formatting and structure.

Comment: You should specify whether the values in your output are the values you actually calculated by hand or if they are just an example of the order of magnitude of the desired result. You should also learn to post either the input code you used or the output of `dput(head(dfrm,10))` so that there is an unambiguous data objerct as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like based on your example you're going off the first value in each Individuals group, so that's what I did for this answer. However, if it is instead the minimum, or if that was an error with your example, please comment and let me know and I'll update it!

```
df |> mutate(across(foodq1:rentq1, ~ first(.x) / first(wage), .names = "pro.{col}"), .by = Individuals)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 8 × 9
  Individuals quarter  wage foodq1 foodq2 rentq1 pro.foodq1 pro.foodq2
        <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1           1 2016q1    100      1      2     50       0.01       0.02
2           1 2016q2    100      1      2     50       0.01       0.02
3           1 2016q3    200      1      2     50       0.01       0.02
4           1 2016q4    300      1      2     50       0.01       0.02
5           2 2016q1     50      1      2     50       0.02       0.04
6           2 2016q2    100      1      2     50       0.02       0.04
7           2 2016q3    200      1      2     50       0.02       0.04
8           2 2016q4    100      1      2     50       0.02       0.04
# ℹ 1 more variable: pro.rentq1 <dbl>
```

Data:

```
df <- tibble(
  Individuals = rep(1:2, each = 4),
  quarter = c("2016q1", "2016q2", "2016q3", "2016q4", "2016q1", "2016q2", "2016q3", "2016q4"),
  wage = c(100, 100, 200, 300, 50, 100, 200, 100),
  foodq1 = 1,
  foodq2 = 2,
  rentq1 = 50)
```